# vs2019 While adding new view getting Erro 'The Templates\PackageVersions5.2.6.xml file is missing from the installed template folder.'

Tags: visual-studio, c#, mvc

VS2019 'The Templates\PackageVersions5.2.6.xml file is missing from the installed template folder.' MVC, C# ?
Create Action Method - Controller 
Right Click - Add View - Throws Error

Comment: Can't understand why it is downvoted ?

Answer (score 2):

Look in your packages.config file. You should find "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.6". Change the 5.26 to 5.2.7 and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the original post is being downvoted.  I had this exact issue and came looking for a solution.

I found that upgrading the "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" package via NuGet to 5.2.7 was not sufficient to fix the problem.  I also had to upgrade "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" and its related packages to 5.2.7.  The Add View option started working again afterward.